# How to prevent function overriding in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my way I usually use to prevent to override `name` property.

```js
let _name = Symbol('name');

class Cat {
    constructor(name) {
        this[_name] = name;
    }
    set name(newName) {
        return this[_name];
    }
    get name() {
     return this[_name];
    }
}

// default name
let cat = new Cat('Hermione');

// new name
cat.name = 'Voldermort';

// testing
console.log(cat.name);
```

My idea: Saving the value of `name` property to another variable.

But if I have multiple class properties, like this:

[image: 1]

that would be wasting to create a lot of variables for saving.

```
let _Min = Symbol('Min'), _Max = Symbol('Max'); // and so on
```

Is there another way to achieve this goal? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way you can get an array of all the properties, such as `name`, `Min`, `Where`, etc? Then you could use a `Proxy` and intercept the set property action.

Comment: It sounds like you'd benefit from [**class inheritance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Then you can define the variables that you want to use in the base class, and only overwrite the required variables in the child class.

Comment: Are you trying to make the object immutable? Like [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)?

Comment: Even within your current concept of having a property with a `Symbol` key, you could use a single such property to refer to an object that in turn has all of the individual properties that you need, accessed in your getters and setters as `this[_props].name`, `this[_props].max`, etc. (I'm not saying that's the best solution, but it's a lot better than creating separate variables and symbols per property.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I've tried again. That's perfectly. I didn't think that I can use same key for all class properties before. Many thanks!

Comment: @everyone Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Sure. Probably should use `const` rather than `let` for that variable, too...

Comment: Usually original properties have to be stored if they are methods that were patched, like `this.method = () => this.originalMethod()`. And they don't have to be stored if they were not.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be read-only, the property should have no `set` accessor:

```
class Foo {
  get bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

If the property is supposed to be defined on construction, the descriptor can be defined too:

```
class Cat {
  constructor(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
      get: () => name,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
}
```

Or

```
class Cat {
  constructor(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
      value: name,
      writable: false,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But using `Object.defineProperty` inside the constructor is weird.I didn't read any documentation like that before.

Comment: There's nothing weird in it. This is core JS feature. The documentation doesn't have to explicitly say that Object.defineProperty can be used inside constructor, or for loop, or another language construction. If it's needed, it's needed. `get` and `set` class methods are just syntactic sugar for Object.defineProperty (you can check how this works in Babel/Typescript transpiled code), but they aren't that sweet if they don't fit the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try following examples, which may solve your problem

**Example 1:**

```
class A {
  a = () => {
    console.log('A#a');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // this will throw error as
  // Class 'A' defines instance member property 'a', but extended class 'B' 
  // defines it as instance member function.
  a() {  
    console.log('B#a')
  }
}

new B().a()

/**
Error: Class 'A' defines instance member property 'a', but extended class 'B' 
defines it as instance member function.
*/
```

**Example 2:**

```
class Renderer {
  constructor(args) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'render', {
      writable: false,
      configurable: true,
      value: () {
         return this.childRender();
      }
    });
  }

  childRender() {
    throw Error('render() is already instance of Renderer. Did you mean? childRender()');
  }

  // do not define methodName() here
}

class Draw extends Renderer {
  render() {
    console.log('DrawB#render');
  }
}

new Draw().render()
/**
VM1597:13 Uncaught Error: render() is already instance of Renderer. Did you mean? childRender()
    at Drawee.childRender (<anonymous>:13:11)
    at Drawee.value (<anonymous>:7:22)
    at <anonymous>:25:14
*/
```

I hope this helps